# Проверка интервалов Python

Tags: python

Не могли бы мне подсказать как возможно оптимизировать данную задачу? На большом кол-ве данных программа требует большого кол-ва времени.

Вход:

1. Первая строка входных данных содержит количество наборов тестовых данных. Затем следуют t наборов.
2. Первая строка набора содержит n отрезков времени. В следующих n строках следуют описания отрезков.

Условия:

1. часы, минуты и секунды заданы корректно (то есть часы находятся в промежутке от 0 до 2, а минуты и секунды — в промежутке от 0 до 59);
2. левая граница отрезка находится не позже его правой границы (но границы могут быть равны);
3. никакая пара отрезков не пересекается (даже в граничных моментах времени).

Необходимо проверить входящие интервалы на данные условия. В случае, если все условия выполняются, то вывести 'YES', иначе вывести 'NO'.

Я написал следующий код:

```
import datetime
import sys


def get_datetime_from_string(str_date):
    try:
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(str_date.rstrip(), '%H:%M:%S')
    except ValueError:
        return None


class Range:
    def __init__(self, start, end):
        self.start_datetime = start
        self.end_datetime = end

    def __repr__(self):
        return f" ({self.start_datetime} - {self.end_datetime})"


def is_intersection(dates, date_range):
    for date in dates:
        if date_range.start_datetime == date.start_datetime or date_range.end_datetime == date.end_datetime \
                or date_range.start_datetime == date.end_datetime or date_range.end_datetime == date.start_datetime:
            return True
        if date_range.start_datetime < date.end_datetime and date.start_datetime < date_range.end_datetime:
            return True
    return False


def main():
    t = int(sys.stdin.readline())
    for i in range(t):
        dates = []
        lines = int(sys.stdin.readline())
        is_no = False
        for line in range(lines):
            if is_no:
                _ = sys.stdin.readline()
                continue
            dt_1, dt_2 = map(get_datetime_from_string, sys.stdin.readline().split('-'))
            if not dt_1 or not dt_2:
                is_no = True
                continue
            if dt_1 > dt_2:
                is_no = True
                continue
            date_range = Range(dt_1, dt_2)
            if is_intersection(dates, date_range):
                is_no = True
                continue
            dates.append(date_range)
        else:
            print('YES') if not is_no else print('NO')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

На вход в консоли поступает:

```
5
1
22:13:56-22:13:55
1
00:00:00-23:59:59
1
23:59:59-00:00:00
2
00:00:00-23:59:59
00:00:00-23:59:59
2
13:44:59-13:44:59
13:45:00-13:45:00
```

Ответ:

```
NO
YES
NO
NO
YES
```

На 100.000 элементах программа уже требует большего времени выполнения и подозреваю, что это из-за считывания ввода, так как даже если у нас валидация не прошла, то обход продолжает. Не могли бы подсказать как можно улучшить данный код?

Использовать можно только стандартные библиотеки.

Comment: так вы саму задачу опишите.

Comment: @strawdog, дополнил описание задачи.

Comment: Не сказано, что требуется узнать

Comment: @MBo, Необходимо проверить входящие интервалы на условия. В текущей задаче их 3. Они описаны в блоке "Условия" в задаче.

Answer (score 1):

Формат времени и перевернутость концов легко фильтровать сразу при считывании. Остаётся проверить пересечение интервалов.

Отсортируйте интервалы по времени начала.

Пройдите по сортированному списку, запоминая максимальное время конца.

Если мы встретили начало интервала, которое меньше или равно времени запомненного конца -  есть пересечение.

Answer (score 0):

Вам помогут векторные операции pandas.

```
import pandas
```

В общем случае это должно выглядеть так (код писать не буду, опишу алгоритм):

1. Вы загружаете весь `stdin` в `pandas.Series`
2. С помощью метода `.apply` cоздаете маску (также тип `pandas.Series`) в которой определяете в каких ячейках содержаться даты (например по наличию символов ':' или '-')
3. Далее с помощью того же `.apply` разделяете даты на старт и финиш (как вы это и делали) и для финиша делаете отдельную `pandas.Series`.
4. И далее выполняете сравнение этих двух серий на нужные вам критерии а по результату снова применяете `.apply`, которая выдаст новую серию с Yes или No. Эту серию и печатаете.

Чудо в том, что операции будут применены к векторам, а не поэлементно, как у вас в коде, все это будет очень быстро, хоть с миллионом объектов.

Comment: к сожалению, необходимо пользоваться только стандартными библиотеками

Comment: Прошу прощения, не обратил внимания на последнюю строку.